# Editing dates in a URL for excel via

Tags: vba, excel

I am a fairly new to vba coding and would appreciate some help as I play around with some code. I am trying to edit a URL to make searching for historical exchange rates dynamic

original code:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=2017-04-20", _
    Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .PostText = "currency_exchange_practice"
```

My new code that doesn't work:

```
Dim dateday, datemonth, dateyear As Long, fulldate As Variant

Columns("A:D").ClearContents

dateday = Day(Range("G2"))
datemonth = Month(Range("G2"))
dateyear = Year(Range("G2"))
fulldate = dateyear & "-" & datemonth & "-" & dateday


With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.x-rates.com/historical/?from=USD&amount=1&date=" & fulldate & "", _
    Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .PostText = "currency_exchange_practice"
```

It is also erasing all my data in cells g2, including a button I have made that are not in cells A:D. Please and thank you for your help!!

Comment: Try `fulldate = format(range("G2"),"yyyy-mm-dd")`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your use of `Month`

`Month` for April will return `4` not `04` so when you pass in `fulldate` to the URL you are passing in `2017-4-20` instead of `2017-04-20`. If I pass in `fulldate` as you have it, I get nothing returned.

To remedy this issue I would first declare your date parts as strings so we can use the `Format` function. An important note here is that you must declare each variable with a datatype. As you have it written, `dateday` and `datemonth` are `Variants` because they are not explicitly given a data type.

`Dim dateday As String, datemonth As String, dateyear As String, fulldate As String`

Then you can do this:

```
dateday = Format(Day(Range("G2")), "00")
datemonth = Format(Month(Range("G2")), "00")
```

Now, `fulldate` will look like `2017-04-20` and should work.

I did confirm that the website you are using expects a two digit value for the day as well.

I am not sure why it would be erasing anything in column G except if your query table somehow overlaps it when it is placed in A1.